# Are DynamoDB global secondary indexes sharded based on their own partition key?

Tags: performance, amazon-dynamodb, scalability, sharding

I'm a little confused about what I'm reading in the DynamoDB help when it comes to their recommendations for partition key design.

On [this first page discussing distributing workload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-uniform-load.html) they explain that it's important to have load distributed across distinct partition keys, since these are used for physical sharding. Makes perfect sense.

But then when explaining global secondary indexes they proceed to doing exactly the opposite in all the examples provided:

- in [this highscore example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-general-sparse-indexes.html) they create a partition key on a key that has a single value! Doesn't this mean that all requests for the high scores (which are "frequently queried" per the problem definition) will hit the same shard?
- in the [GSI overloading example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-gsi-overloading.html), they suggest creating a GSI that uses the table's sort key as its partition key, then performing searches e.g. by `Employee_Name` - but `Employee_Name` is a partition key in the GSI, so again wouldn't all these requests hit the same shard?

Aren't these examples going to create hot partitions on the GSI and thus suffer from scaling issues? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: The example talks about sparse index, when every row of your table will have that key, it will no longer be a sparse index.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right and these examples are indeed wrong for exactly the reasons you cited.

I think in the GSI overloading example, they switched the partition and sort key around - I opened an issue about that many months ago explaining why I think that - see https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-dynamodb-developer-guide/issues/202 - but so far it wasn't fixed (or nobody came back to explain to me why the example was right).